# Custom Change Password Page

Tags: forgot-password

Is there a way to change the HTML markup of the page where you change your password(the page you go to when clicking on the reset password link sent to your email)?

I would like it to match the look and feel of my EE site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use custom system messages which sets up the EE specialty templates as editable files:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages

Or freemember which allows you to use your own templates for member specific actions:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember

I've used libraree previously as it gives access to system templates as well as saving globals & snippets as files as well:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/libraree

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use one of the great members as entries add-ons ([Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit), [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor), [Safecracker Registration](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/safecracker-registration)), which bridge the gab between the member module and channel entries, they provide a mechanism for you to access member data in regular templates (making it considerably easier to do whatever you need to do in terms of look and feel, etc.).  [Freemember](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember) does some of that unshackling as well, but I don't know that it uses channel entries for the member data at all.

Comment: When you say that "Safecracker Registration provides a mechanism for you to access member data in regular templates," what does that mean?

Comment: The "entries as members" add-ons all perform in slightly different ways, but the end result is effectively the same - your member accounts are setup as channel entries (just like the rest of your content) and are therefore much easier for you to use within regular EE templates.  The add-ons do still use the member module to create an actual member record for the user - they just synchronize the changes between the member channel entry and the member module member record (for those fields that are required at the very least, such as username, email and password).